# C++ Advanced Lint error "Skipping CppCheck linter because lintOn 1 is not in 2."

Tags: visual-studio-code, cppcheck

I am running VSCode from Windows over an SSH connection to a Centos 7 development machine and I get the error "Skipping CppCheck linter because lintOn 1 is not in 2."
This was working perfectly and I have no idea what might have changed to provoke the error.  I do not get any squiggles denoting issues in the code editor.  I have been unable to find any help online.

My settings.json in the project .vscode directory reads:

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "istream": "cpp",
        "ostream": "cpp",
        "fstream": "cpp",
        "sstream": "cpp"
    },
    "c-cpp-flylint.enable": true,
    "c-cpp-flylint.debug": true,
    "c-cpp-flylint.flexelint.enable": false,
    "c-cpp-flylint.cppcheck.enable": true,
    "c-cpp-flylint.clang.enable": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would seem to be a bug in the extension and has been reported to the maintainer